# LINQ concatenate values from associated tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

Let'say there's a basic SQL db with the following structure:

#### Customers table

Customer ID
Name
PostCode
Email

#### Orders table

Order ID
Customer ID
Description

#### Items table

Item ID
Order ID
Name
Cost

So a customer can have many orders and an order can have many items.

What's the most appropriate LINQ query to run in order to achieve the following result where the Order Item Names result is a comma separated string:

**Customer Name | Customer Email | Order Item Names**

So effectively the Orders table is acting like a link table between the Customer and Order Items tables. I then want to concatenate the names of all items which are associated with all orders into a single string and return it in the same result as the customer details.

I've got the following working as expected which will return a result for each order item:

```
IQueryable<CustomerSearchResult> customerSearchResult = from customer in db.Customers
                         join order in db.Orders on customers.CustomerId equals order.CustomerId
                         join item in db.OrderItems on order.OrderId equals item.OrderId
                         where customerId.Equals(userId)
                         select new CustomerSearchResult {
                             customerName = customer.Name,
                             customerEmail = customer.Email,
                             itemName = item.Name
                         };
```

**EDIT 21st March 2014**

There are some cases when there will be no associated OrderItems in which case the CustomerSearchResult should still be returned but with the ItemNames property empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you have results

```
var query = from c in db.Customers
            join o in db.Orders on c.CustomerId equals o.CustomerId
            join i in db.OrderItems on o.OrderId equals i.OrderId
            where c.CustomerId == userId
            select new {
                CustomerName = c.Name,
                CustomerEmail = c.Email,
                ItemName = i.Name
            };
```

Group them and concatenate item names:

```
 var result = from r in query.AsEnumerable()
              group r by new { r.CustomerName, r.CustomerEmail } into g
              select new CustomerSearchResult {
                 CustomerName = g.Key.CustomerName,
                 CustomerEmail = g.Key.CustomerEmail,
                 ItemNames = String.Join(",", g.Select(r => r.ItemName))
              };
```

You should do names concatenation in-memory, because EF will not be able to translate it into SQL.

Comment: +1 from me AND I would like to add a recommendation, that is, to use a `VIEW` in your database that unifies these tables virtually in the DB, then it's a snap to just query the `VIEW`. Much easier and faster than doing all the joining etc. in your application/service.

Comment: @Sergey Thanks Sergey, great answer. However I've recently discovered that there are some cases when there will be no associated OrderItems in which case the CustomerSearchResult should still be returned but with the ItemNames property empty.